# i want data life ,if i type 'a' all data related to a appears,i want this for all alphabets

Tags: django

What should i do if i want the data as per my alphabet(for any alphabet)

```
def list(self,request):
    ...
    try:
        user=add_category.objects.filter(i)
        users=[]
        for i in user:
            users.append({
                'addcategory':i.addcategory
            })
        return Response({'data':users})
    except Exception as error:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False}, 
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Hi! Please explaine what exactly you need with examples. It's not obvious what is the "data as per my alphabet".

Comment: user=add_category.objects.filter(i) here i will return data according to my input,if i type 'a' then output will all data starts with 'a',my question is,if i enter any word ,the data starts withv that words should appear.

Comment: this could be done, but first you need to show your model

Comment: class add_category(models.Model):
    addcategory=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.addcategory

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains):

```
add_category.objects.filter(addcategory__icontains=i)
```

, where `i` is your user input.

Also, note that in Python class names should starts with [uppercase](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id41). This is a naming conventions.